# Как в Java вывести в консоль значения атрибутов из файла XML?

Tags: xml

Подскажите как в Java вывести в консоль значения атрибутов из файла XML?
Чтобы получались такие строки вывода:

> Ivanov 12 A red
>   Petrov 20 B blue

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Data>
  <Title>

  <Obj name="Ivanov" id="12" raz="A">
    <Value><![CDATA[red]]></Value>
  </Obj>


  <Obj name="Petrov" id="20" raz="B">
    <Value><![CDATA[blue]]></Value>
  </Obj>

  <!-- Ещё 18 Obj -->

  </Title>
</Data>
```

Comment: А на каком языке программирования вы пытались реализовать задачу?

Comment: Как в Java вывести в консоль значения атрибутов из файла XML?

Answer (score 2):

Можете использовать DOM парсер из стандартной библиотеки, например:

```
try {
    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = documentBuilder.parse(new File(fileName)); // fileName - путь до xml
    Element root = document.getDocumentElement();

    NodeList list = root.getElementsByTagName("Obj");
    for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
        Element element = (Element) list.item(i);
        System.out.println(element.getAttribute("name") + " " + element.getAttribute("id") + " " + element.getAttribute("raz") + " " + element.getTextContent());
    }
} catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```